# CDF of Sum of a Guassian and Exponential random varaible

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $X$ is a Gaussian random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and $Y$ is an exponential random variable with mean $\lambda$ then what will be the CDF of the $Z=X+Y$?

Actually it will become $$P(Z\leq P)=\int_0^P\frac{1}{2}erf(\frac{P-x}{\sqrt{2}})e^{-x}dx$$ assuming $\mu=0$ $\sigma^2=1$ and $\lambda=1$.

But I dont know how to proceed further.
BR
Frank

Comment: $erf$ is an ugly function. $1-F_Z(z)=\int_R \phi(x)\min(1,e^{-(z-x)})\,dx$ and you can break up the integral into two part.

Comment: @ A.S. But can we use the following formula (I just found it on the internet) $$\int erf(ax)e^{bx}dx=\frac{1}{b}erf(ax)-\frac{1}{b}exp(\frac{b^2}{4a^2})erf(ax-\frac{b}{2a})$$.

Answer (score 0):

Comment: In case it helps, the ECDF plot
from a simulation of 10,000 points in R should
be reasonably close to the exact CDF.

```
 m = 10^4;  x = rnorm(m);  y = rexp(m);  z = x+y
 plot.ecdf(z, pch=".")
 abline(v=0, col="green3")
```

[image]